# Data extraction from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Data in table `A`:

```
X   Y
------
m1  r1
m1  r2
m1  r3
m2  r1
m2  r4
m2  r5
```

Data in Table `B`:

```
Z
--
r1
r2
r3
r4
r5
```

---

Using a query I want a result like

```
m1  r4
m1  r5
m2  r2
m2  r3
```

The data required from join of two sample tables so that data corresponding to column `Y` which is not in table `B`. I have already developed a solution using cursors and inserting data in the table but that's is causing performance issues like 10 hours for 125122 distinct rows of column `X` in table `A`. I want a query where insertion operations are not involved so that we can save some disk I/O operations and optimize the performance.

Comment: Please give us the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE A\G (and for B). Then give us INSERT INTO A(B) VALUES(....)). This will help us to help you without having to go to the trouble of figuring out these statements for ourselves. Take the tour and read the "help us to help you" blog (bottom left of page).

Answer (score 0):

It is not nice - sort of anti-join

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb0124/3

```
SELECT a1.x, b.z
FROM (
        (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM a) a1,
        b
     ) LEFT JOIN a a2 ON (b.z = a2.y AND a2.x=a1.x)
WHERE a2.x IS NULL;
```

Comment: (You need to fix some of the table and column names to be consistent with the question.)

Comment: @RickJames thanks for noticing, I somehow messed up..